# Istio AuthorizationPolicy only for external requests

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Right now I'm having 3 services. A, B and C. They all are running in the same namespace. I'm making use of the `EnvoyFilter` to transcode the `http` requests to `grpc` calls.

Now I want to add security for those calls but I want each service to allow internal communication as well.

So I only want to check external requests for authentication.

Right now I have the following `RequestAuthentication`:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: jwt-authentication
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      sup.security: jwt-authentication
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "http://keycloak-http/auth/realms/supporters"
    jwksUri: "http://keycloak-http/auth/realms/supporters/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
```

Then I added the following `AuthorizationPolicy`:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
  name: "auth-policy-deny-default"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      sup.security: jwt-authentication
  action: DENY
  rules: []
```

How do I configure istio in a way that it allows intercommunication without checking for authentication?

Comment: can you share the envoyfilter to transcode http calls to grpc

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach in Istio is not to think from the perspective of what you want to deny, but of what you want to allow, and then deny everything else.

To deny everything *else* create a catch-all deny rule as shown below:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
spec:
  {}
```

Now what you need to do is decide what are the cases when you want to allow requests. In your case, it would be:

- All authenticated requests from within the cluster achieved with `principals: ["*"]`.
- All authenticated requests with a valid jwt token achieved with `requestPrincipals: ["*"]`

Putting those together give the policy below:

```
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
 name: "allow-all-in-cluster-and-authenticated"
 namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
spec:
  rules:                                 
  - from:
    - source:
        principals: ["*"]
    - source:
        requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

The field `principals` has a value only if a workload can identify itself via a certificate (it must have the istio proxy) during PeerAuthentication. And the field `requestPrincipals` is extracted from the jwt token during RequestAuthentication.

Please let me know if it doesn't work or there are tweaks needed :)

Comment: Thanks for your example but this seems to cause some issues... now the services can't call the auth service in the init container.

`Connecting to keycloak-http.core.svc.cluster.local (10.98.7.49:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
`

Comment: Uh! That is important information. Test this out:
1. Delete the first policy.
2. Apply the second policy only to the istio ingress gateway by using selectors: `spec.selector.matchLabels.app: istio-ingressgateway` and update the namespace to istio-system. No other changes needed.